Rusty v8 error: "Failed to run custom build command for `v8 v0.92.0`"
I'm trying to install screenpipe on Windows.
The installation steps are the following:

Install dependencies using Chocolatey: choco install ffmpeg pkgconfiglite rust git ✔️
Clone the repository: git clone https://github.com/louis030195/screen-pipe ✔️
Change the directory: cd screen-pipe ✔️
Build the API: cargo build --release ❌
Run the API: ./target/release/screenpipe

I got stuck at Step 4. I'm getting the following error:
error: failed to run custom build command for `v8 v0.92.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\xxxxx\screen-pipe\target\release\build\v8-521073ea328981d1\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=.gn
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=BUILD.gn
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/binding.cc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CCACHE
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CLANG_BASE_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXSTDLIB
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=DENO_TRYBUILD
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=DOCS_RS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=GN
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=GN_ARGS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=NINJA
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OUT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=RUSTY_V8_ARCHIVE
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=RUSTY_V8_MIRROR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SCCACHE
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=V8_FORCE_DEBUG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=V8_FROM_SOURCE
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PYTHON
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=DISABLE_CLANG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=EXTRA_GN_ARGS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=NO_PRINT_GN_ARGS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CARGO_ENCODED_RUSTFLAGS
  cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=rusty_v8
  cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=winmm
  cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=dbghelp
  download lockfile: "C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\screen-pipe\\target\\release\\build\\lib_download.fslock"
  static lib URL: https://github.com/denoland/rusty_v8/releases/download/v0.92.0/rusty_v8_release_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu.lib.gz
  cargo:rustc-link-search=C:\Users\xxxxx\screen-pipe\target\release\gn_out\obj
  Looking for download in '"C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\.cargo\\.rusty_v8\\https___github_com_denoland_rusty_v8_releases_download_v0_92_0_rusty_v8_release_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu_lib_gz"'
  Downloading (using Python) https://github.com/denoland/rusty_v8/releases/download/v0.92.0/rusty_v8_release_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu.lib.gz
  Python downloader failed, trying with curl.

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at C:\Users\xxxxx\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\v8-0.92.0\build.rs:513:3:
  assertion failed: status.success()
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...

What does this error mean?

Looks like rusty_v8 only provides binaries for the msvc toolchain on Windows, not the GNU toolchain: https://github.com/denoland/rusty_v8/releases/tag/v0.92.0

@Jmb I talked with the author of the screenpipe. There was a bug. After git pull and rebuild, the error was gone. Thanks for the help anyway.

Question was already answered in the comments by the original author:
You need to perform a git pull and a rebuild afterwards.
